# Create Layered Image in TVML (tvOS)

Tags: tvos, tvml

I'd like to create a layered image for use on tvOS 9.0 using TVML markup.

This seems like it should be a relatively common problem, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do this (as of tvOS Beta 3).  In the Apple TVML demo app it accomplishes this by using multi-layer images that are [pre-compiled into a single .lsr file](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/), rather than in markup with each layer separately noted.

It is possible to script the creation of .lsr files using the `layerutil` CLI program, but this would be a huge hassle for the app I'm trying to build where the images will be user-generated-content.

Instead it would be great to be able to do something like this (note the `src-layer1` property for adding an extra layer above the base `src`):

```xml
<lockup>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ/mqdefault.jpg" src-layer1="https://server.com/path/to/overlay.png" height="180" width="320"/>
  <title>Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up</title>
</lockup>
```

Is there any other efficient way to do this other than scripting a lot of back and forth to a server to generate a .lsr file?

*Update - Oct 21 2015:* At the [bottom of this documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/ResourceValues.html) Apple provides a checkmark overlay image that would be perfect for this use called `resource://button-play`.  But there still seems to be no way to use this icon overlay in TVML. :-/

[image]

Comment: To be clear, I don't think there's a way to do this (at least as of tvOS 9.0 Beta 3), but I'd like to know if that changes in the future.  Please don't answer with "Can't be done." etc.

Comment: Agreed - this seems like something that will be supported in code eventually

Answer (score 3):

You can use `overlay` for layering images in lockups.

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/CoumpoundDisplayElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH18-SW3

```
<lockup>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ/mqdefault.jpg" height="180" width="320"/>
  <title>Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up</title>
  <overlay style="padding:0;">
    <badge src="resource://overlay-checkmark" />
  </overlay>
</lockup>
```

Comment: Thanks cem! I read the linked documentation and there doesn't seem to be any way to control position so my overlay checkmark just ends up towards the middle of the image. Is there positional information that I'm missing?

Comment: I also tried creating my own overly badge image that was sized exactly the same as the lockup background img then setting the src to point to this full overlay on my webserver, but it wouldn't display any image.  Tried a few variations with no luck.  Not allowed to here perhaps?

Comment: Here's a picture of how it's currently placed following your `overlay` & `badge` example above: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vemd7.png

Comment: lets try giving `padding:0;` as `style` attribute for `overlay`

Comment: So adding the `padding:0` did move the checkmark but it still didn't make it to the corner: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nzRlx.png Weird. Thanks for all your help though!

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to have trouble positioning the check mark overlay, try padding it with transparency so that it is the same aspect ratio as the video thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  It would be perfectly reasonable for that to work and so I actually [tried that a while ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008104/create-layered-image-in-tvml-tvos/34812079#comment56989412_34499526), but TVML wouldn't load HTTPS-served images for the overlay.